# How to ignore case in string comparison

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have an Excel VBA formula:-

```
If [G56] = "Not Applicable" Then
    ...
```

It is case-sensitive. I want it to ignore the case of "Not applicable".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use the LCase function:

```
If LCase([G56]) = "not applicable" Then
```

Comment: or the `UCase$()` function, just for arguments sake ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the dedicated function for comparing strings:

```
Dim result As Integer

'// vbTextCompare does a case-insensitive comparison
result = StrComp("Not Applicable", "NOT APPLICABLE", vbTextCompare)

If result = 0 Then
    '// text matches
End If
```

There is some more information on the `StrCompare` method in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s233cfc(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Upvoted `StrCompare` but Binary is quicker. http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html

Answer (score 4):

Or add `Option Compare Text` at the top of the Module:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub Test()
 MsgBox "Not Applicable" = "Not applicable" 'True
End Sub
```

Comment: That's the nicest option that fixes all case-related bugs.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Fastest option would be

```
StrComp(LCase$("Not Applicable"), "not applicable", vbBinaryCompare)
```