# VBA nested if, with changing output cells position

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build my dream macros and this is the final step, that just should insert formulas into cells under certain conditions. There are multiple conditions: first I scan first row for certain text values, if there are text that met condition 1 I proceed to scan column A for another text values, if condition 2 are met I want to proceed with formula. Here are screenshot to understand my request better:

[image]

Yellow are cells i want to fill with simple formula (column C / column B).
-First condition before fulfil the cell is row 1 suppose to contain certain text (xyz in my example).
-Then if row 1 contain value im looking for, i want to check column A (range A2:A) to check if column contain "end". If there are no end proceed to insert formula into cell D2-3...100 etc, until column A contain "end" then stop the macros and proceed further.
Also must mention, that column B is constant and never change.

Main issue why I need such complicated formula is that there are might be unlimited number of columns that needs to be analysed.

My solution looks very primitive, and it works for the first column D, I do understand that my use of offset is the reason why macros doesn't insert formulas into cells > D, but I'm confused is there a way to improve my solution or I should look into completely different direction?

```
Sub formula_insert()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, rngone As Range, LstRow As Long
        
        Set rngone = Range("1:1")
        
        For Each cell In rngone
            If InStr(1, cell.Text, "xyz", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, cell.Text, "yxz", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            
                LstRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                For Each rng In .Range("A2:A" & LstRow)
                    If LCase(rng.Value) = "end" Then
                        Exit For
                    Else
                    
                    rng.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=RC[-1]/RC[-2]"
                    
                    End If
                    
                Next rng
                
            Else
                
            End If
            
        Next cell
    
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `rng.Offset(0, 3).FormulaR1C1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub formula_insert()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cHdr As range, cA As range, txt, LstRow As Long, rngA As range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    'occupied cells in Col A
    Set rngA = ws.range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)
    
    'loop over row 1
    For Each cHdr In ws.range("A1", ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        txt = cHdr.Text
        If InStr(1, txt, "xyz", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
           InStr(1, txt, "yxz", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then 
            For Each cA In rngA.Cells
                If cA.Value = "end" Then Exit For
                'place the formula in same row as cA, one column to right of cHdr
                ws.Cells(cA.row, cHdr.Column + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/RC2"
            Next cA
        End If
    Next cHdr
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much man, i much appreciate your efforts. May be i was not clear enough, but your formula keep retracting divide value from wrong cell. It always should be $B, but thank you very much, based on my very primitive analyse and compare your solution with one that worked, you were very close!.

Comment: My bad - edited above.

Comment: I’m shy to ask, but is there a way to use function vbtextcompare on step where program check either cell value = “end”?

Comment: `If LCase(cA.Value) = "end" Then Exit For` or see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42319239/478884 for how to use `StrComp`

Comment: FYI you'd already selected a working answer I think which was more efficient than this?

Comment: On scale I find out that your solution is simpler to apply, im very bad with range values, there for i choose your answer. Thank you very much for help with StrComp too.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your picture, I can recommend:

```
Sub formula_insert()
    Dim cell As Range, i As Integer
    For Each cell In Range([A2], [A1].End(xlDown))
        If cell = "end" Then Exit For
    Next
    i = cell.Row - 2 ' find the end first, offset from the first row
    For Each cell In Range([С1], [A1].End(xlToRight))
        If InStr(1, cell.Text, "xyz", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
            InStr(1, cell.Text, "yxz", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Range(cell.Offset(1, 1), cell.Offset(i, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/RC2" ' set the range at once
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

It's general recommendation based on provided information.

Comment: Wow, @rotabot it works just perfect for me. Very interesting solution. Thank you very much buddy.

Comment: This solution is more efficient than Tim's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, 'rng.Offset(0, 3).Formula' will put to the column D regardless of where the "xyz" or "yxz" is found.

```
Change: rng.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=RC[-1]/RC[-2]"
To:     rng.Offset(0, cell.Column).Formula = "=RC[-1]/RC[-2]"
```